# User Defined Runtime Attributes working only in simulator, not on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I'm setting an attribute called target with Interface Builder.

[image: like so]

This works fine on the simulator. However when I change the destination to my iPhone and run the app, the value does not get picked up. I get (null) when I try and access the target attribute. What could be the issue?

I'm trying to access the value in viewDidLoad method of my view controller.

Comment: It may related to xib name. because simulator doesn't care about case sensitive but device doesn't. Did you check with xib?

Comment: Yep, key path case is same in the storyboard as the value in the view controller class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a memory management issue. While defining the target property in the class, I had defined the storage as weak. Changing it to strong fixed this.